# Convert List<Foo>.Property to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, slice

Is there a way to do this efficiently in C#?

**Given:**

```
List<Thing> listOfThings = new List<Thing>() {};
```

**Desired Output:**

```
String[] thingNames = (Gather up all the (string)Thing.Name values into an array)
Int[] thingID = (Gather up all the (int)Thing.ID values into an array)
```

I know there is a *listOfThings.ToArray()* but what I need is something like *listOfThings.Name.ToArray()* and *listOfThings.ID.ToArray()*.

In the end, I desire to take these arrays and use them for Oracle Array Binding.

Thank you,

~ Shaun

Comment: _efficiently_ - then use classic `foreach` loop, other way you will get bunch of LINQ answers

Comment: @Fabio actually `for` loop would be a tiny bit better than `foreach`.

Comment: efficiently could mean anything.  Most efficient?  Which version of .NET?  Are you ok with the fact performance changes and will potentially change again in the future?  This question lacks the proper constraints to make it a good question.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ `Select()` and `ToArray()`:

```
var names = listOfThings.Select(th => th.Name).ToArray();
var ids = listOfThings.Select(th => th.ID).ToArray();
```

Make sure this is at the top of the .cs file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

By "efficiently", do you mean fast, parsimonious in use of memory, or do you just want fewer characters in the source file? Usually, if people are concerned about optimizing for performance or memory, we advise them to do some metrics to be sure there's really an issue. It's usually wise to optimize for readability first, and simply *not pessimize* for the others.

Comment: Ed, I am glad to accept your answer as it offers me a way to accomplish the goal.  I have never used .Select in that way.  Thank you, I learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it the old-fashioned way, using a `for` loop. It should be a little faster since you're only iterating over the collection of `listOfThings` one time (this becomes more noticeable as the number of items in the original list and grows):

```
string[] thingNames = new string[listOfThings.Count];
int[] thingIds = new int[listOfThings.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < listOfThings.Count; i++)
{
    thingNames[i] = listOfThings[i].Name;
    thingIds[i] = listOfThings[i].ID;
}
```

Comment: Iterating one time with two actions inside loop and iterating two times with one action inside loop will be quiet similar for performance, both approaches will still have O(1)

Answer (score 0):

I had some free time at work and decided to test the speed between the two posted methods (For vs LINQ). I create a list filled with 1 million `Foo` objects each with an `int ID` and a `string Name`, as per your question. I repeated the process of the conversion 100 times to get a better average of the time it takes to make the arrays. Results are as follows:

```
# of items in list: 1000000
# of trials: 1000
LINQ(Avg): 62.946ms
FOR(Avg): 19.82ms
```

The LINQ method is ~3x slower than the pure `for` loop, for data sets of this size. But overall, the difference is minuscule in the grand scheme of things. I still prefer the LINQ option for its readability, even if it is technically slower.

Comment: This isn't precisely an answer, but I think it's a valuable contribution to the discussion and it would be an awkward fit as a comment.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah, I wish I could mark it somehow as like auxiliary information, but alas this is the best option. I'd never post it unless there was already answers to test. I don't even care about reputation for things like this, I just wanted to share my findings on the speed of the two methods.